# Set up GitHub workflow from existing YAML

Tags: github-actions

I have a YAML pipeline that I want to run, but I can't work out how to tell GitHub to use my file and stop it from creating a new one.

The yaml file is in `.github/workflows` in my `develop` branch.

In GitHub, under Actions, if I click "set up a workflow yourself" it takes me to:

[image]

The path is correct but it's defaulting to the default `master` branch and clicking on `master` just takes me to the `code` view. I can't find a way to change it to `develop`

I believe the relevant part of the code is:

```
name: CI

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
```

If I understand [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-manually-trigger-a-github-actions-workflow-4712542f1960) correctly, `workflow_dispatch` should allow it to be run manually, but it doesn't appear to be listed.

I'm sure this is 101, but I can't work it out. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful if you could share them, please.

## Update 1

After @flaxon showed me how to change the URL to point to the correct branch, I am still unable to run a workflow. Even if I let GitHub create a new workflow, there's no option to run it. When I go to actions, this is all I see:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Merge to master branch.

For reasons I don't understand, one has to merge `develop` into `master`. Maybe it's something to do with the default branch and if I had committed against `master` it wouldn't have been a problem. Anyhow, going to `Action` gives me the **Workflows**  section and the `workflow_dispatch` attribute allows me to run it manually.

(I did wonder if it was to do with the push branch set to `master`, but changing it to develop made no difference).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can change it in the URL,

***/test-workflow/new/**develop**?filename=.github%2Fworkflows%2Fmain.yml&workflow_template=blank

Comment: Thanks. That solves changing the branch, but there must be another issue as GitHub is not picking up the fact that there is already a workflow yaml file there. Even if I let it create one, I have no option to run it.

Comment: they did an assumption that you use master to configure your actions, so because you don't have the file there they try to make it again